# UV Unwrap and Normal Baking Issues

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

OK, So Im working on retopology for a model. I did a smart UV unwrap on the model, decided i didnt like the way it unwrapped. I deleted the UVMap that was created, added some seams, and unwrapped again. I baked my normals from the HP mesh to the LP UVs... The baking worked perfectly as when I import into a game engine, I dont have ANY issues with the normal maps. The problem lies with when i render in blender. Below are two images, The first from the mesh that was freshly exported to FBX and imported into Unity.

[image]

The second image is Blender 2.80.75 showing a few highlighted faces so you can see what is going on.

[image]

Im not sure if this is a bug, or i'm totally missing something. Any advice would be GREATLY appreciated. but as you can see the arrow should be pointing to horizontal lines... the normal bake next to the blender image even shows that. Ive tried to disconnect and reconnect, force the node editor to use the one and only UVMap from the unwrap. Ive tried deleting the UVMap and unwrapping again. Im just hoping maybe someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks for your help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcVKk.jpg

Comment: Your screenshots are very low resolution, so its hard to see whats going on, can you add larger ones?

Comment: @Sazerac ya, I will tonight, sorry about that.

Comment: @Sazerac I added an imgur link (https://imgur.com/a/xjpgLQ0) notice that in the UV Editor window, the faces that are highlighted should translate into horizontal lines, rather than the diagonal lines that are shown at the arrow.

Comment: Have you added a UV map to the Vector input on your image texture? If thats not the problem, can you add a blend with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: @Sazerac I did at Vector Input in the node editor. So I think i figured out where the issue was. I started working on this character with the beta blender 2.8. I exported the FBX and then inported it into the final release of blender 2.8 and the issue doesnt happen anymore. I appreciate your help though!!!